# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I am making a ecommerce website by following the tutorial, using next js, react js and sanity. The application was running file up until I got the api key in order to connect to sanity. After I put in the key, I started getting the error below, I even clicked on the link and followed the steps, nothing worked, followed something that was mentioned here and it didn't work.

Error:

Failed to compile:

```
./sanity_ecommerce/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.d.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> export type Platform = 'browser' | 'node' | 'neutral';
| export type Format = 'iife' | 'cjs' | 'esm';
| export type Loader = 'base64' | 'binary' | 'copy' | 'css' | 'dataurl' | 'default' | 'empty' | 'file' | 'js' | 'json' | 'jsx' | 'text' | 'ts' | 'tsx';
```

this is my code

```
import sanityCli from '@/sanity_ecommerce/sanity.cli';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = sanityCli({
  projectId: '78rabqwa',
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2023-06-30',
  useCdn: true,
  token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);

and may package:
```

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sanity/client": "^6.1.5",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",
    "esbuild": "^0.18.10",
    "eslint": "8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.7",
    "next": "13.4.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4"
  }
}
```